# How can I setup IntelliJ to remember Git Bash current working directory between sessions?

Tags: windows, intellij-idea, git-bash

I'm running IntelliJ 2018.3 on Windows 7, as well as openSUSE Leap 15.
Under Windows 7, I've configured IntelliJ to use Git Bash, i.e., in Settings, under `Tools -> Terminal`, I'm setting `Shell path` to:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git_2.17.1\bin\bash.exe
```

One of IntelliJ's new features is the ability to save and reload terminal sessions (see [this link](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/whatsnew/#v2018-3-terminal)).

It works perfectly with openSUSE, however, on Windows, while the terminal tab names are correctly restored, I always end up with a new shell.

Is there a way to make IntelliJ and Git Bash play well together so that I can retain the current working directory and shell history after restarting IntelliJ?

Comment: have a look to this link if this helps.https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-system-console.html. Also it mentions it will retain the state of the directory after Intellj restart.

Comment: Hi @RohitMahajan. Thanks. I'm using the System console exactly as described in the link that you provided. Unfortunately, it only saves the current working directory and history in openSUSE. I'm not sure it is a problem with my configuration, IntelliJ or Git Bash.

Comment: Just to add some extra info. I've also tried with `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git_2.17.1\bin\sh.exe" --login -i` and it is still not saving the current path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a possible workaround. It was heavily inspired by [VonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54272614/664577), as well as other answers to the [question that he mentioned](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32508/how-can-i-open-a-new-terminal-in-the-same-directory-of-the-last-used-one-from-a).

#### ~/.bashrc

```
if [[ -v __INTELLIJ_COMMAND_HISTFILE__ ]]; then
    __INTELLIJ_SESSION_LASTDIR__="$(cygpath -u "${__INTELLIJ_COMMAND_HISTFILE__%history*}lastdir${__INTELLIJ_COMMAND_HISTFILE__##*history}")"

    # save path on cd
    function cd {
        builtin cd $@
        pwd > $__INTELLIJ_SESSION_LASTDIR__
    }

    # restore last saved path
    [ -r "$__INTELLIJ_SESSION_LASTDIR__" ] && cd $(<"$__INTELLIJ_SESSION_LASTDIR__")
fi
```

I don't like the fact that I had to wrap the `cd` command, however Git Bash does not execute `~/.bash_logout` unless I explicitly call `exit` or `logout`; unfortunately due to this limitation, the `.bash_logout` variant is inadequate for the mentioned scenario.

The  workaround above also leave small junk files inside `__INTELLIJ_COMMAND_HISTFILE__` parent dir, however, I couldn't do any better.

Additionally I've opened [a ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-205795) in Jetbrain's issue tracker. There are many different shells that may benefit from official support. It would be great if JetBrains could eventually support [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) and popular terminals like  [windows-subsystem-for-linux](/questions/tagged/windows-subsystem-for-linux), [cygwin](/questions/tagged/cygwin) and [git-bash](/questions/tagged/git-bash). The only shell that currently works out of the box for me is [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd).

Comment: Interesting workaround. +1. More complete than my answer.

Comment: @VonC, yeah, your solution is certainly cleaner. Unfortunately Git Bash is not executing`~/.bash_logout` as expected. `trap` is also not picking up `SIGHUP` nor `EXIT` signals unless I explicitly type `exit`.

Comment: Just to confirm that the above solution also works on Cygwin.

Comment: Hi there, since this feature is still not available, I tried your solution -
But the project-speciofic history is not saved. i did not find any  no local histfile in the project - any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Hi @mtness, I'm no longer using Windows nor Git Bash and I assume that the internal mechanics of this have evolved since 2019. Other than upvoting the issue that I created so that JetBrains implement a solution, my other suggestion would be to move to WSL 2 and install tmux (this is what I did before I moved on from working with Windows).

Comment: @Anthony Accioly
Thank you very much, Yeah, will have to reconsider the current workflow then, too.

Answer (score 3):

You can try and setup your Git for Windows bash to *remember* the last used path for you, as seen in "[How can I open a new terminal in the same directory of the last used one from a window manager keybind?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/32508/7490)"

For instance:

So instead of storing the path at every invocation of cd the last path can be saved at exit.

> My `~/.bash_logout` is very simple:
>
> ```
> echo $PWD >~/.lastdir
> ```
>
> And somewhere in my `.bashrc` I placed this line:
>
> ```
> [ -r ~/.lastdir ] && cd $(<~/.lastdir)
> ```

That does not depend on Intellij IDEA directly, but on the underlying bash setup (here the Git for Windows bash referenced and used by Intellij IDEA.

Comment: This looks promising. Unfortunately, as it stands, it will bring all terminals, across every tab / window to the last directory accessed. I'm trying to preserve the current working directory per tab. Looks like IntelliJ makes some variables like `__INTELLIJ_COMMAND_HISTFILE__=C:\Users\Anthony\.IntelliJIdea2018.3\config\terminal\history\history-11` available per tab. I may be able to identify the current terminal and save / reload a separate file per tab that way. I'll report back.